# Joining twin files (with the same name but different extensions) in bash script

Tags: bash

I have thousands of pair files with .txt and .svs extinctions like:

```
A.S.txt A.S.svs Bi.W.txt Bi.W.svs .....
```

I would like to apply a command like "join" on each pair using bash script. Any idea how to do that with a single line of code?

Something like:

```
join A.S.txt A.S.svs > A.S
join Bi.W.txt Bi.W.svs > Bi.W
```

Comment: Can you be clearer about exactly what you are trying to do? Do you want to combined the pairs of files with the same basename?

Comment: @ Tom Fenech: exactly! I am going to clarify the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combined `A.S.txt` with `A.S.svs`, then `Bi.W.txt` with `Bi.W.svs`, etc., you could use a `for` loop:

```
for f in *.txt; do b=$(basename "$f" .txt); cat "$f" "$b.svs" > "$b.both"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
cat A.S.* Bi.W.* >> A.S.B
```

That's what cat is is best at :)

Comment: I think you missed the point: the OP does not want to concatenate every file into one.